# How to insert checkbox data of selected value?

Tags: php, checkbox

Hi i am trying to insert checkbox data Yes/No of selected customer. Selected customer (who's value is retrieved from database) if checked yes then Y will be inserted in table field and if checked no then N will be inserted in table field. I can't find out the solution to do so, tried it!

Thanks for help in advance.
Here is what i have so far;

```
<table width="400" border="1" bordercolor="#598DD5">
<tr>
<td bordercolor="#598DD5" bgcolor="#598dd5"><span class="style1">Projects</span></td>
<td bordercolor="#598DD5" bgcolor="#598dd5"><span class="style1">Hot Project</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bordercolor="#598DD5"><select name="customer">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY customer ORDER BY customer";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["customer"]."'".($row["customer"]==$_REQUEST["customer"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["customer"]."</option>";
} ?>
</select></td>
<td bordercolor="#598DD5">   
<div align="center"> 
Yes <input type="checkbox" name="hotproject" value="Y" <?php if( isset( $_GET['customer'] ) ){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />
No  <input type="checkbox" name="hotproject" value="N" <?php if( isset( $_GET['customer'] ) ){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /></div>      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your checkbox code is only testing if `$_GET['customer']` exists.  If it does, both checkboxes are set as checked.  You probably want to test `$_GET['customer']` for a specific value.  Also, this may be place to try a radio button since you probably don't want both yes and no checked at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript with jQuery for change the value of checkbox
OR
Change the type "checkbox" to "radio" with the same name of the input.

Here : http://jsbin.com/UPuQ/1/edit